# Why does sysinfo list my CPU as having 1,6GHz when I have an i5-2300 CPU @ 2.80GHz?

Tags: system, cpu, cpufreq

I would like to know whether there could be a driver I'm missing, since **sysinfo** can't see  the correct value for my CPU frequency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably just because the processor frequency has dropped to save power due to it being idle. If you run a processor intensive task and look again you should hopefully see the correct frequency.

You can also see this information by running `cat /proc/cpuinfo` in a command line. For example, my computer has one core currently heavily loaded. Along with a load of other information I get this for the heavily loaded core:

> model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         950  @ 3.07GHz
>
> cpu MHz         : 3060.000

So that just about matches up with the 3.07GHz. For another core I get:

> model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         950  @ 3.07GHz
>
> cpu MHz         : 1596.000

The current frequency is halved over the maximum.

Comment: Ok I'll try loading `sysinfo` again when I'm running a cpu-intensive task. I'll come back then to tick your answer.